# Simple auto email alert in PHP

Tags: php, email, alerts

I need to implement a simple email alert in PHP.

The question is:

There is anyway to send emails without access directly the web page?

I tought in something like this: every access of anyone, the system run a "trigger" (routine) to send every emails need for that date...

Any better idea?

Comment: you can set up a [cronjob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to send emails at specific times or any time interval you want.

Answer (score 2):

Make php script and then set a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) on server for the time interval you need to send mails.